# automatic connect to hidden wifi

Tags: network-manager

The hidden status of the Wi-Fi network I am being allowed to connect to is not my option.   I am using that Wi-Fi network now, to post this question.  every time I boot up Ubuntu 16.04 LTS it fails to connect there, pops up a message saying that Wi-Fi networks are available (there are 5 non-hidden ones that are not usable) and I must manually select "Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network ..." and manually type in the SSID, select the type of "Wi-Fi security", and enter the password.  It works fine until I reboot.  At times when I am at other locations, other networks which are not hidden work automatically just fine after I select it once.  I want to have this network saved and automatically connected when I reboot.  How can I get that?

Comment: at least one of the non-hidden networks does not require a password. maybe that is influencing the logic of NetworkManager.

Comment: There's unanswered questions, what network manager are you using, has the network name previously been changed, and have you cleared any uuid's from the previous hotspots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently a known problem; see [Launchpad bug 1542733](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1542733).

Possible manual workaround: use `nmcli`:

```
nmcli c up id "connection name"
```

Comment: i am disappointed in the software NetworkManager.