# 20.04 can't remember hidden WiFi SSID

Tags: wireless

Lately Ubuntu 20.04 cannot remember to connect automatically to my home wifi, whose SSID is hidden.
It used to do.
Now I must explicitly connect each time I reboot.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I created a text-file on my desktop named "wifi_connect.sh" with the content:

```
nmcli c up id "SSID"
```

where SSID is the name of my network, as proposed here: [automatic connect to hidden wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044345/automatic-connect-to-hidden-wifi)

I can double click it to connect to my wifi, which is faster than clicking through the wifi options.

Nevertheless, I would prefer that Ubuntu automatically connects to the wifi as it did before the update to 20.04.